# Gdata library specifically for Android

Tags: android, google-docs-api, gdata-api, google-drive-api

```
import com.google.gdata.client.docs.DocsService;
import com.google.gdata.util.AuthenticationException;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.*;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.clientlogin.*;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.*;
import com.google.api.client.http.*;

import java.io.*;

public class AccountFeedExample {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, AuthenticationException {
      DocsService service = new DocsService("Document List Demo");
      service.setUserCredentials("username","password");
    }
  }
```

I am trying to run the above code as an Android application but the apk crashes. I think the Gdata library is Java specific. Is there any Gdata Android-specific library that I can use in my application?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Google Drive client library (and not the Google Document List Client Library). As discussed in a few other questions, the GData client library do not work well on Android.

Documentation to the Google Drive API: https://developers.google.com/drive/

You'll need to download the Drive specific wrapper: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/APIs#Drive_API

And the core of the library with the dependencies: http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/downloads/list